# Custom domain for github using internetbs

Tags: github, dns, subdomain, github-pages

I'm trying to configure the dns for my domain to target one of my pages in github

I'm currently using https://internetbs.net for domains but I can't seem to configure it correctly.

I tried searching for a solution but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also use internetbs for my domains, and have hosted on github pages.This is how I got it working:

**From Github**
On your github pages branch (master for github user page, or gh-pages if it a project page) create a CNAME file. In it put just your domain, ie

```
thedomainyouhavebought.com
```

And commit this file (you can check its linked in the repo settings on in the github pages section.

**From Internetbs.net**
login on [internetbs](https://internetbs.net). Select your domain, and go to "DNS Management" section.
In here I set both the *A Records* and *CNAME Records*.

In A Records leave the name blank, and and in the IP section point it towards:

```
192.30.252.152
```

Add another A record that points towards:

```
192.30.252.153
```

In CNAME section, add the alias `www`, and then type the Host location on GitHub, for example if it is a [github user pages](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/) site you will type:

```
username.github.io
```

For me it took about 10 mins to update.

You can check the its linked typing the following in to your terminal:

```
dig thedomainyouhavebought.com.
```

In the answer section, you should see a link to github pages.

for more info visit 
https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/
https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/